# Get data from mouse events in plot.ly or ggvis within r (not shiny)

Tags: r, plotly, ggvis

I want to use interactive plots in R to be able to select x intervals in plots, i have tried plot.ly and ggvis and it seems that the mouse click on the plot followed by horizontal drag, used for zooming is exactly what i want, but zoom would have to be disabled and the [x start, x end] values must be returned to R. Any ideas if this is possible, and if so, how?

Comment: From my understanding `ggvis` and `plotly` generate static HTML pages with embedded javascript and data. They cannot "talk" to R after they have been rendered. This is different from `shiny` where an active R session is maintained for the lifetime of the web server. If you need two-way communication between the plot and R I don't think `ggvis` or `plotly` can help you.

Comment: Any idea on what can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Depends on your exact requirements. But `shiny` would be a good place to start.

Comment: Shiny Gadgets may be a good option for this. They work work like full Shiny, but create short-lived applications that return values to an R session upon termination. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/gadgets.html

Comment: you can use `event_data` in `plotly` to make the charts interact with each other based on selections.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make tooltip function available with static_output (without shiny).
You can check my fork (https://github.com/lujiacn/ggvis
), enable the tooltip by default, in Rstudio and output html widget.

The way is put tooltip content in one variable called "tooltip". If no "tooltip" variable, wills show the all values linked to the data.